# ExpressJS POST Method Request Issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am running into an issue where I am trying to run a POST request via Postman and I get a loading request for a long time and then a `Could not get any response` message. There are no errors that are appearing in terminal. Is it the way I am saving the POST? Specifically looking at my /blog route.

server.js

```
//Load express
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router(); // get an instance of the router
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
// configure app to use bodyParser()
// get data from a POST method
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080; // set the port


var blogDB = require('./config/blogDB.js');

var Blogpost = require('./app/models/blogModel');

app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); // set ejs as the view engine

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); // set the public directory



var routes = require('./app/routes');
// use routes.js
app.use(routes);


app.listen(port);
console.log('magic is happening on port' + port);
```

blogModel.js:

```
var mongoose    = require('mongoose');
var Schema      = mongoose.Schema;

var BlogPostSchema  = new Schema({
        title : String,
        body : String,
        date_created : Date
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Blogpost', BlogPostSchema);
```

routes.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var blogDB = require('../config/blogDB.js');
var Blogpost = require('./models/blogModel.js');

//index
    router.route('/')
    .get(function(req, res) {
    var drinks = [
            {   name: 'Bloody Mary', drunkness: 3 },
            {   name: 'Martini', drunkness: 5 },
            {   name: 'Scotch', drunkness: 10}
        ];

        var tagline = "Lets do this.";

        res.render('pages/index', {
            drinks: drinks,
            tagline: tagline
        });
    });

//blog
    router.route('/blog') 

        .get(function(req, res) {
            res.send('This is the blog page');
        })

        .post(function(req, res) {

            var blogpost = new Blogpost(); // create a new instance of a Blogpost model
            blogpost.title = req.body.name; // set the blog title
            blogpost.body = req.body.body; // set the blog content
            blogpost.date_created = Date.now();

            blogpost.save(function(err) {
                if (err)
                    res.send(err);

                res.json({ message: 'Blog created.' });
            });

        });




//about
    router.get('/about', function(req, res) {
            res.render('pages/about');
    });


module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Have you tried to output something to the console in your callback function ?Is `blogpost` defined ? Does the `save` method succeed ?

Comment: @WaldoJeffers `blogpost` is defined in the post method of the `router.route('/blog')`. When I run a post request in Postman, I get a long Loading... notification that never ends. There is no message being posted that says `Blog created.`, which I used as the success message. Could this be an issue with how I set up mongodb configuration?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I did not setup a user for my Mongo database. Basically it couldn't gain access to the user/pw to the database that I was using. Once I created a user matching the user/pw I included in my url, then I was able to get a successful post.